# Object with one key as default (getter/setter)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know with all the new ECMAScript6 stuff we're having some amazing things happening. My goal was to do something like this I don't know if its possible:

```
var angEl = {
  get(): blah,
  scope: this.scope(),
  injector: this.injector()
}
```

Right now I do it like this:

```
var angEl = blah;
var angElProps = {
  scope: angEl.scope(),
  injector: angEl.injector()
}
```

Just wondering if there is any cool new hip way to accheive this.

Comment: What's wrong with `{scope: blah.scope(), injector: blah.injector()}`?

Comment: Can you show a use case? What's wrong with the "Right now" solution?

Comment: Thanks @Amit no issues with what im doign now just trying to be cool and hip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading two things, you want to assign values and methods.

The best way to do this in ES5 is to put the values for this in an constructor function that will run when you run new MyObject(value). Then assign the methods to the prototype. If you put the methods in the constructor, it can cause problems with the same function getting created again and again.

ES5

```
var MyObject = function(value){
    this.value = value;
}

MyObject.prototype.func = function(){};
```

ES6 has cleaner looking syntax when you're not going to be taking advantage of manually editing object prototypes and just want a class-like object.

ES6

```
class MyObject{
 constructor(value){
   this.value = value;
 }
 func(){}
}
```

Edit: Also, ES6 has get and set built in.

```
class MyObject{


     func(){}
     set value(value){
         this._value = value;
     }
     get value(){
         return this._value;
     }

}
```

Comment: `get` and `set` were already in ES5, btw. They're neither making anything "private", nor will they work well with recursively assigning/accessing themselves.

Comment: @bergi - Oh cool, I didn't know they were in ES5, I said '"private" like' because it's syntax familiar to people who do class oop, I should note that there's only privacy by scope, and the best way to do privacy would be an immediately invoked anonymous function. Thanks for improving the answer.

Comment: @yatg no problem, and thanks for the kind words. As Bergi mentioned get and set were available earlier. I've never used those, as you could have probably guessed from the follow up!

Comment: I removed the reference to private like to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's still getting stack overflow exceptions, though…

Comment: Which one? Is there a JSFiddle or CodePen link? I find myself regretting answering the question now, due to vagueness of the original and what was trying to be achieved... :) But you have been awesome, which is why I'm following up.

Comment: Try `new MyObject().value` or `new MyObject().value = 0` with the setter/getter example :-)

Comment: It should be _value or another name. Another awesome catch. Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly es6 but it sounds like you want to use something like Object.defineProperty() or Object.defineProperties().
For example:

```
var angEl = {};
Object.defineProperties(angEl, {
  'scope': {
    get: function() {
      return this.scope;
    },
    set: function(val) {
      this.scope = val;
    },
    value: //set to something
  },
  'injector': {
    ...
  }
});
```

This way you can define exactly how you interact with your object, internally to itself without the need for the extra object.

Comment: Getters and setters that recursively call themselves are a very bad idea…